# Assembly binding redirect in Azure Functions

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, azure-functions, assembly-binding-redirect

I have created an Azure function and as we know it has the package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.8 which is dependent on Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1.

I have added another class library as a reference to this Azure Function which depends on Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2.

During runtime, I get an error stating:

> "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified."

This looks like a problem related to Assembly Binding Redirects so I follow this solution to try and fix
https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/07/21/how-to-fix-the-assembly-binding-redirect-problem-in-azure-functions/
But, this doesn't help as well.

Is there a step that I'm missing or any other workaround for this kind of case? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did your problem get solved?

Answer (score 4):

Azure functions don't have a notion of binding redirect. If your functions app has a reference to a library that depends on a specific version (say version x) of `Newtonsoft.Json` and the `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions` has implicit dependency on another version (say version y), as a workaround you can add explicit reference to version x of `Newtonsoft.Json` in your functions app by running this on your Package Manager Console.

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version x`

This will make your project dependency show a yellow warning sign but you won't get a runtime error.

[image]