# How can I resolve this NewtonSoft version conflict?

Tags: azure, dependencies, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm working on an Azure function. I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared, which requires NewtonSoft v11, so I've implemented some manual binding redirects with the app domain which seems to be working (see below). But somehow, there is a hard reference to the WebJob app domain that NewtonSoft is conflicting with if I'm reading the log below correctly:

> 2018-05-21T22:03:03.824 [Info] Exception:
>   [A]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cannot be cast to
>   [B]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Type A originates from
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11702\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in the context
>   'LoadNeither' in a byte array.

My Newtonsoft v11 dll is in the function's bin directory and is referenced there like so:

```
#r "bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
```

There is actual code in the function that works correctly in the function:

```
dynamic eventHubMessage =
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(myEventHubMessage);
```

But when it hits this line:

```
CRSLTwinData twinData = IotHubProxy.GetTwinData(hubDeviceId);
```

It throws the exception. The reference to M.A.D.Shared and Newtonsoft 11 is therein.

I've tried everything I can to get the function to use the 11 version of the dll,  but something is obviously out of whack.

UPDATE: we tried redirecting to 9 instead and got this:

> 2018-05-22T13:24:48.336 [Info] Exception: [A]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cannot be cast to
>   [B]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Type A originates from
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11702\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in the context
>   'LoadFrom' at location 'D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\e801054b\3f30c00f\assembly\dl3\e5381214\00f64e9a_9af1d301\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.

Then we tried redirect to 10 and got this :):

> 2018-05-22T14:16:14.509 [Info] Exception:
>   [A]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject cannot be cast to
>   [B]Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Type A originates from
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11702\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in the context
>   'LoadFrom' at location 'D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\e801054b\3f30c00f\assembly\dl3\e5381214\00f64e9a_9af1d301\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.

Comment: Do you actually use anything specific to v11?

Comment: Nope, not that I can tell. Are you thinking a binding redirect back to 9?

Comment: While I'm not using anything specific to 11, the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared may be internally.

Comment: If you don't use any specific of v11, you can set `Specific version` to false on references to Newtonsoft.Json.dll in your project(s) properties. It should solve your problem.

Comment: But that won't cover the references for Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared, will it?

Comment: I double-checked it, and I'm not even referencing NewtonSoft in the CRSLTwinData lib.

Comment: Did you try to downgrade redirect version to 9? Does you code work in this case?

Comment: Perhaps try adding explicit reference in the functions app that will override the implicit version used by the functions SDK? I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149343/assembly-binding-redirect-in-azure-functions/50182222#50182222

Comment: Actually - ignore my comment. It looks like you're not using the precompiled functions app, you're using the individual script files. My answer on the other thread isn't applicable here.

Comment: Could you offer some details for your `CRSLTwinData` and `GetTwinData`? They may reference `Newtonsoft.Json` internally.

Comment: They do - they reference version 11 internally, necessarily because of an Azure library reference.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using azure function 1.0 which has known [assembly resolution problem](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Assembly-Resolution-in-Azure-Functions).

Since webjob use strict version number of Newtonsoft json, what I have done in my project is to downgrade all mine to inline with the sdk's

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.13, which consumes Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3

Comment: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.13 also depends on 9.0.1

Comment: They might have changed it then. We have used 1.0.13 and worked well.